# Capistrano 3 + rbenv + sidekiq: Command not found

Tags: ruby, capistrano, sidekiq, rbenv, capistrano3

I'm upgrading to Capistrano 3, and during deploy sidekiq should start. But I'm getting the following error:

```
00:23 sidekiq:start
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec sidekiq --index 0 --pidfile /var/www/my_app/shared/tmp/pids/sidekiq-0.pid --environment staging --logfile …
      01 rbenv: sidekiq: command not found
      01
      01 The `sidekiq' command exists in these Ruby versions:
      01   1.9.3-p429
      01
```

I don't use the system ruby or rbenv default ruby version for this project. I have the ruby version set in my `VirtualHost` apache configuration:

```
PassengerRuby /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby
```

and `$ rbenv versions` returns

```
  1.9.3-p429
* 2.1.2 (set by /home/deploy/.rbenv/version)
  2.3.1
```

This is my `Capfile`

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require "capistrano/setup"

# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"
require 'capistrano/sidekiq'
require "whenever/capistrano"
require 'airbrake/capistrano/tasks'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/passenger'

Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

And this is my `deploy.rb`

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.6.1'

server '123.456.789.0', user: 'my_user', roles: %w{web app db}

set :application, 'my_app'
set :repo_url, 'git@server.com:/myApp'
set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true }
set :passenger_restart_with_touch, true
set :migration_role, :app
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.3.1'
set :rbenv_map_bins, ['rake', 'gem', 'bundle', 'ruby', 'rails', 'sidekiq', 'sidekiqctl']

set :default_env, ->{ { rack_env: fetch(:rails_env) } }

set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'public/system')
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/config.yml')

after 'deploy:finished', 'airbrake:deploy'

set :whenever_command_environment_variables, ->{ { rack_env: fetch(:whenever_environment) } }
set :whenever_environment,  ->{ fetch :rack_env, fetch(:stage, "production") }
set :whenever_identifier, ->{ "#{fetch(:application)}_#{fetch(:stage)}" }

set :sidekiq_env, -> { fetch(:rails_env) }
set :sidekiq_concurrency, 5
set :sidekiq_require, './lib/sidekiq_runner.rb'
set :sidekiq_queue, ['high', 'low']
```

And my `deploy/staging.rb` (there is also a production.rb):

```
set :rails_env, "staging"
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/my_app"

role :web, "123.456.789.0"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "123.456.789.0"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "123.456.789.0", primary: true # This is where Rails migrations will run
```

- I'm not sure if the capistrano rbenv gem really uses the ruby 2.3.1 version for the deployment. I'm pretty sure that has something to do with it. But I don't know how to debug this
- The original command with capistrano 2 to start sidekiq was `set :sidekiq_cmd, defer { "bundle exec sidekiq -c5 -r ./lib/load_feeds/sidekiq_runner.rb -q high -q low" }`
- I'm deploying a sinatra app, and it uses `ENV["RACK_ENV"]` for configuration files. Therefore the mix between rails env and rack env

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have multiple ruby versions installed at your server and they aren't well configured. The message showed that your current deploy process, which set at `deploy.rb` as v.2.3.1 , can't run `sidekiq:start` because there is sidekiq process that still running using v.1.9.3-p429.

```
01 The `sidekiq' command exists in these Ruby versions:
01   1.9.3-p429
```

When you want to deploy using different `rbenv_ruby` version, don't forget to stop current sidekiq process first by using previously deployed `rbenv_version`, in this case, v.1.9.3-p429 that showed at the message, at `deploy.rb`

```
set :rbenv_ruby, '1.9.3-p429'
```

and then do

```
$ cap production sidekiq:stop
```

It is better to follow ruby version  of your server's apache configuration, in your case v.2.3.1. So you have to change your server global ruby version from v.2.1.2 to v.2.3.1:

```
$ rbenv global 2.3.1
$ rbenv rehash
```

and if you check again `$ rbenv version` it will return

```
  1.9.3-p429
  2.1.2
* 2.3.1 (set by /home/deploy/.rbenv/version)
```

Note: To change the global version is not necessary especialy if you have more than one `VirtualHost` with different ruby version.

The most important thing is: before re-deploy using different ruby version, don't forget to make sure no sidekiq process running with previous deployed ruby version. Additionally, make sure your `rbenv_ruby` version setting to follow `VirtualHost` ruby versions at `deploy.rb`:

```
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.3.1'
```

Do `cap production deploy` again and you will get no `rbenv: sidekiq: command not found` error anymore and apache error too.